# Using a different Manager with refresh_from_db()

Tags: python, django, orm

I have model set up in a way that it never gets deleted, instead a status is updated to status 'DELETED'. To achieve this I have overridden the delete() method as following

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    self.status = Booking.DELETED
    self.save()
```

And added two custom managers to track deleted an non deleted bookings, the standard manager is swapped with on that only returns non deleted objects.

```
class BookingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(status=Booking.DELETED)

class BookingDeletedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Booking.DELETED)

class Booking(models.Model):
    PAYED = 0
    PENDING = 1
    OPEN = 2
    CANCELLED = 3
    DELETED = 4
    objects = BookingManager()
    deleted_objects = BookingDeletedManager()
...
```

Now when i have a booking object and delete it like this

```
booking.delete()
```

And refresh it like this

```
booking.refresh_from_db()
```

I get the error

```
.models.DoesNotExist: Booking matching query does not exist
```

If i use the correct manager

```
Booking.deleted_objects.get(pk=booking.id)
```

I get the booking correctly presented to me, I am assuming the refresh_from_db method used the standard objects manager which does not find the correct Booking. is there a way to get around this or am i approaching this problem wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`refresh_from_db` is just a method inside `models.Model` class so you can override it inside the `Booking` model. See here for the source:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.refresh_from_db

You just need to change `db_instance_qs` to use `BookingDeletedManager()`

Comment: Okay, and if i want to have a method where i can pass the manager to, i will have to overload the method?

Comment: If I were you, I would create an abstract `BaseModel` class which inherits from `models.Model` and then use that as parent to `Booking` model or other models I might need in the future. That way the code will be much cleaner and you won't have to repeat similar code all over the code base. Also if you ever need to change things in the future, you won't have to do it from each and every model class. Instead you can do it from a single place